# Anylogic: UPDATE table and get value of parameter

Tags: anylogic

I try to run with for-loops through different parameter names and try to store their value in a table with UPDATE. The "+AktuellerParameterWert+" statement in the UPDATE statement just shows the name of the parameter, not the value of the parameter as intended. The parameters are declared on the graphical interface of Anylogic, have names like "Parameter12" and contain int values. I guess the UPDATE statement can't make a connection to the parameter on the graphical interface. Any help regarding those two problems would be greatly appreciated :)

Error: root:
Error occurred when executing SQL query in modify() method
Caused by: user lacks privilege or object not found: PARAMETER11 in statement [UPDATE konfigurations_matrix SET station1=Parameter11 WHERE produktionsschritte = 'A']

```
int AnzahlAvgs=4;       
int AnzahlStationen=2;  

int AvgCount;       
int StationenCount; 

String ParameterName = "Parameter";
String AktuellerParameterWert;
String Station = "station";
String AktuelleStation;
String Produktionsschritt;


for (StationenCount=1; StationenCount<=AnzahlStationen; StationenCount++) {

for (AvgCount=1; AvgCount<=AnzahlAvgs; AvgCount++) {


AktuellerParameterWert = ParameterName + StationenCount + AvgCount;


System.out.println(AktuellerParameterWert);     
        
AktuelleStation = Station + StationenCount;

Produktionsschritt = String.valueOf((char)(StationenCount + 64));

executeStatement("UPDATE konfigurations_matrix SET '"+AktuelleStation+"'="+AktuellerParameterWert+" WHERE produktionsschritte = '"+Produktionsschritt+"'"); 


   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not referencing the parameter properly from where you call the SQL code.

You need to refer to your parameter in its proper location, relative to from where you are calling the SQL statement. This is basic OOP and very important to understand. Search the AnyLogic help for "where am I and how do I get to" to learn more.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Benjamin! My parameters and my function are both in my main. I tried several combinations with the info from Anylogic help, but it didn't work.

If I just put the specific parameter name into my UPDATE statement like "+Parameter11+", the right value is stored in my table. But if I use "+AktuellerParameterWert+" and try to iterate with the for loop through the different parameter names, it doesn't work. I tried putting main. in front of the parameter name, but not luck. Is it even possible to iterate though the parameternames and access their values?

Comment: You can only iterate over iterable things. You can put params into a collection (if they have the same type) and loop across those. But then your SQL statement must be within that loop. Select several params and right-click: there is an option to add to a collection

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!! I got it to work with the collection :) Great to have the possibility to ask you and the community, makes learning and coding a lot more fun!! Have a nice evening :)

Comment: @Pumluk if the answer was helpful, please upvote it. Helps others find it faster in the future when they have similar problems :)